# opengl :find the max and the min in a row or column of a texture

Tags: opengl

I am looking for a method which allows to determine the max value of rows or columns of a texture
here is an explanatory figure attached
thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwP9y.png)

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the CPU or the GPU? How do you define "max value" for a texel? What do you want to do with that value?

Comment: This is not easily parallelizable and thus unsuitable for the gpu

Comment: im try to do it with gpu